# Variadic template parameters and policies

Tags: templates, c++11, policy

I'm writting a policy based logging system while learning a bit of C++ as a hobby. Seems to be a pretty classic exercise. But I have run into a problem I can't solve.

I'm using a variadic template to pass any parameters in the Sink constructorto the writerPolicy as some of the policies need a parameter.

```
template <class FilterPolicy, class FormatterPolicy ,class WriterPolicy, class ...Ts>
class Sink
    {
    public:
    Sink(Ts ... p_args) : m_filter(), m_formatter(), m_writer(p_args...){}

    virtual void ProcessLogEntry(const Log::LogEntry &data) ;
    private:
    FilterPolicy m_filter;
    FormatterPolicy m_formatter;
    WriterPolicy m_writer;
    };
```

The headache starts when I realise that the other policies also might need zero or more parameters passed on to them in the constructor of sink.

Obviously we can't write:

```
Sink(T1s ... v1s, T2s ... v2s, T3s ... v3s) : m_filter(v1s...), m_formatter(v2...), m_writer(v3s...){}
```

But I can't get my head around this template thing and come up with a good solution, that lets the Sink template figure out which arguments go with witch policies.

My goal is to be able to write

```
Sink<FilterOnLogLevelPolicy,HTMLFormatPolicy,FileWriterPolicy>(log::DEBUG,"log.html");
```

and have Sink pass the first argument to FilerOnLogLevelPolicy (which takes one parameter in its constructor), none to HTMLFormatPolicy which takes no parameter and the 2nd argument to FileWriterPolicy which needs a filename in the constructor.

**HOW?**

Comment: So each policy class has its own set of constructor parameters, and you need to forward them to the members of your logger class?

Comment: You could emulate the way maps work, and accept a "piecewise" tuple constructor: `m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(a1, a2, a3), std::forward_as_tuple(b1, b2))`

Comment: @KerrekSB thats exactly what I'm thinking. Bo, you have an error on the constructor. The template (`Ts...`) should be on the ctor, becuase in jour examples you are not passing any types to it at the template instantation.

Comment: @Manu343726 Yes.. Some policies require no constructor parameters, others multiple. It varies for each policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not "outsource" the construction to the client, they're her types anyway so she knows how to build them (see [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)).

```
template <class FilterPolicy, class FormatterPolicy, class WriterPolicy>
class Sink
{
public:
    Sink(FilterPolicy filter,
         FormatterPolicy formatter,
         WriterPolicy writer) :
      m_filter(std::move(filter)),
      m_formatter(std::move(formatter)),
      m_writer(std::move(writer)) {}

    virtual void ProcessLogEntry(const Log::LogEntry &data);

private:
    FilterPolicy m_filter;
    FormatterPolicy m_formatter;
    WriterPolicy m_writer;
};
```

This results in the declaration syntax:

```
Sink<FilterOnLogLevelPolicy,HTMLFormatPolicy,FileWriterPolicy> sink(
  {log::DEBUG}, {}, {"log.html"}
);
```

Allowing the user to perform as complicated or as simple an initialization as she likes.

Comment: I would also probably suggest default implementations for each class.

Comment: This does require movability of your subcomponents.

Comment: Its one of these moments where I realize I still have A LOT to learn... The solution is painfully simple when you see it :-)